# how to resolve StackOverFlowError?

Tags: java, class, exception, package, outer-join

My Inner and outer class file here:-

```
package com.demo;

public class Outer {
int outer_x=100;

void test(){
    Inner inner =new Inner();
    inner.display();
}
public class Inner {
void display(){
    Outer ob=new Outer();
    ob.test();

    System.out.println("display: outer_x= "+outer_x);
}
}

}
```

Another  main class acess outer class member :-

```
package com.demo;

class InnerClassDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Outer outer=new Outer();
        outer.test();
    }
}
```

Exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.demo.Outer.<init>(Outer.java:3)
    at com.demo.Outer$Inner.display(Outer.java:12)
    at com.demo.Outer.test(Outer.java:8)
```

How can resolve this issue ,pls give me any idea?

Comment: Follow your execution in the `test()` method.

Comment: which kind of error in test() method i acess the inner class method

Comment: Outer --> Inner --> Outer --> Inner --> Outer --> inner --> ........ StackOverFlowException

Comment: I still love questions about StackOverflows on this site :)

Comment: can pls  someone edit my code why this error occure

Comment: Welcome to the world of recursion!

Comment: @MadConan its not recursion topic

Comment: @user2860053:  Yes it is.  What you are doing is recursively calling test and then display.  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: @MadConan i am not agree this statement

Comment: @user2860053: How is it NOT recursion?

Comment: @MadConan I dont know why you are talking its recurrsion but now i study example of nested and inner class including static and non_static nested class i know recurrion is a prosses of defining items  itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `test` method creates an `Inner` and calls its `display()` method, which creates an `Outer` and calls its `test` method.  Nothing in your code stops this from continuing forever, until enough methods have been called to fill up the stack space and a `StackOverflowError` occurs.

Either don't have `test` call `display`, or don't have `display` call `test`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this  issue  from @rgettman answer modified my Inner and outer class  here

```
package com.demo;
public class Outer {
int outer_x=100;

void test(){
    Inner inner =new Inner();
    inner.display();
}
public class Inner {
void display(){

    System.out.println("display: outer_x= "+outer_x);
}
}

}
```

Comment: FYI - This should go in an edit to your question, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for giving new advice @Okuma.Scott

Answer (score 0):

Outer.test calls Inner.display which calls Outer.test which calls Inner.display which calls Outer.test which calls Inner.display which...

This goes on until your program runs out of stack space.

Answer (score 0):

You get StackOverFlowError, because your call has a infinite method call which always exceeds program stack.

Your test method calls display and display method calls testunconditionaly.

It is the basic requirement to define a base case for recursive methods, so you should define a base case which will return and stop recursive method calls.

**See also**

[Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Comment: its not recurrsion @erencan

Comment: you also create instances recursively and call only one time its methods. In the end, yes it is recursion.